# How to add method under button in FloatLayout, Python + Kivy

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I want to assign a method under button to do for example

- print text in console
- exit form

I have main python file as follows:

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout

class MyGeneralForm(App):
    def build(self):
        return FloatLayout()

    def btnTestEnviron(self):
        print("Print this on console")

    def btnClose(self):
        self.root_window.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyGeneralForm().run()
```

Please correct me if I am wrong:

1. I define class MyGeneralForm which inherit after Class App from Kivy
2. I am not sure why I define this method "Build" which return "FloatLayout" -> does it behave like constructor of the class and returns layout from Kivy File?
3. I define two additional methods in the class: btnTestEnviron and btnClose which I would like to print sth. in console and close the form/app
4. name = main -> Execute the script whenever you run this particular python file -> it creates the object of class MyGeneralForm and uses method "run" which I understand is inherited after "App" from Kivy? 
   Why is it not something like:

```
TestApp = MyGeneralForm()    #I set the object of class MyGeneralForm   
TestApp.run()                #I use method run from object TestApp (inherited from App)
```

Now I have Kivy File as follows:

```
<Button>:
    font_size:20
    color:0.3,0.6,0.7,1
    size_hint: 0.4, 0.2

<FloatLayout>:
    Button:
        id: btnTestEnviron
        pos_hint: {"x":0.3,"y":0.75}
        text: "Run on test Environment"
        background_color: 0.3,0.4,0.5,1
        on_press: root.btnTestEnviron()

    Button:
        id: btnExit
        pos_hint: {"x":0.3,"y":0.0}
        text: "Exit"
        background_color: 0.3,0.4,0.5,1
        on_press: root.btnClose()
```

5. I define properties of all widgets -> to be precise buttons -> their font, color, width, height
6. Then I create FloatLayout in which I create two buttons
7. How do I associate methods (btnTestEnviron, btnClose) from my class (MyGeneralForm) with those buttons? Program runs properly, but when I click the button I receive following error:

```
   File "kivy\weakproxy.pyx", line 32, in kivy.weakproxy.WeakProxy.__getattr__

AttributeError: 'FloatLayout' object has no attribute 'btnTestEnviron'

    File "kivy\weakproxy.pyx", line 32, in kivy.weakproxy.WeakProxy.__getattr__

AttributeError: 'FloatLayout' object has no attribute 'btnClose'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didnt define your button funtions in the Layout class
This is the correct code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout

class FloatLayout(FloatLayout):
    def btnTestEnviron(self):
        print("Print this on console")

    def btnClose(self):
        App.get_running_app().stop()

class MyGeneralFormApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return FloatLayout()

    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyGeneralFormApp().run()
```